# Remove empty decimal with .droplast() in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to remove empty trailing decimals and instead of using an extension for float I want to consider using droplast() if the result has any trailing zeros:

```
            if result.contains(".0") {
                result.characters.dropLast()
            }

            if result.contains(".00") {
                result.characters.dropLast(2)
            }
```

This does not seem to work and I get the warning:

> Result of call to 'droplast()' is unused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution using regular expression, the number of decimal places doesn't matter:

```
var result = "1.00"
result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\.0+$", 
                          with: "", 
                       options: .regularExpression, 
                         range: result.startIndex..<result.endIndex)
```

Considering the entire string you can even omit the `range` parameter:

```
result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\.0+$", 
                          with: "", 
                       options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: That worked thank you but it will take me some time to understand all of it :D specifically the range bit... but thank you in any event!!!

Comment: The *range bit* is of type `Range<String.Index>` which can be created with the half-open range operator `..<`. The `range` parameter can even be omitted in this case. The regular expression pattern searches *a dot (`\\.`) followed by one or more zero digits (`0+`) at the end of the string (`$`)*

Comment: @Brewski:  In Swift 3, the `range:` parameter is optional and you can simply omit it.

Answer (score 1):

**dropLast method** will return a subsequence that leaves off the dropped items, so in this case it won't modify the **result variable**, then you would need to create a new **String** based on the result of **dropLast method call** and assign it to **result variable**.

```
var result: String = "1.00"
var dropCount = getTrailingDecimalCount(from: result)
print(dropCount) // outputs 2

if let dropCount = dropCount {
  result = String(result.characters.dropLast(dropCount))
  print(result) // outputs 1.
}
```

---

```
func getTrailingDecimalCount(from string: String) -> Int? {
  var counter = 0

  guard string.characters.contains(".") else {
    return nil
  }

  for char in string.characters.reversed() {
    if char == "." {
      break
    }

    counter = counter + 1
  }

  return counter
}
```